# How can I view file history in Git?

Tags: git, timeline, git-diff, git-log, revision-history

With Subversion I could use [TortoiseSVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to view the history/log of a file.

How can I do this with Git?

I am just looking for the history record for a particular file, and then the ability to compare the different versions.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to view the commit history. Each commit has an associated revision specifier that is a hash key (e.g. `14b8d0982044b0c49f7a855e396206ee65c0e787` and `b410ad4619d296f9d37f0db3d0ff5b9066838b39`). To view the difference between two different commits, use [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the first few characters of the revision specifiers of both commits, like so:

```
# diff between commits 14b8... and b410...
git diff 14b8..b410
# only include diff of specified files
git diff 14b8..b410 path/to/file/a path/to/file/b
```

If you want to get an overview over all the differences that happened from commit to commit, use `git log` or [`git whatchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged) with the patch option:

```
# include patch displays in the commit history
git log -p
git whatchanged -p
# only get history of those commits that touch specified paths
git log path/a path/b
git whatchanged path/c path/d
```

Comment: Thanks for the -p tip, that's super useful for finding which revisions involved a bit of code.

Answer (score 116):

It looks like you want [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) and/or [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). Also check out [gitk](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html):

```
gitk path/to/file
git diff path/to/file
git log path/to/file
```

Comment: Here's another nod for gitk, which provides a great way to browse all snapshots of a single file in a git repo.

Comment: By default gitk shows the diff plus 10 lines of context, but what if you want to see a snapshot of the whole file? Simply set "Lines of context" to a large value (e.g. 100000). Then you can flip back and forth between commits and see the entire file at different points in time. (You can also search within the file.)

Comment: Does gitk work on Windows? If so, what environment is required?

Answer (score 53):

My favorite is `git log -p <filename>`, which will give you a history of all the commits of the given file as well as the diffs for each commit.

Answer (score 39):

I like to use **gitk name_of_file**

This shows a nice list of the changes that happened to a file at each commit, instead of showing the changes to all the files. Makes it easier to track down something that happened.

Answer (score 35):

You could also use [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) for a nice, [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)-based Git repository browser. To view history of a file:

```
tig path/to/file
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 11):

Many Git history browsers, including `git log` (and 'git log --graph'), [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) (in [Tcl/Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), part of Git), QGit (in Qt), tig (text mode interface to Git, using [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)), Giggle (in [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK)), TortoiseGit and [git-cheetah](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/MSysGit:GitCheetah) support path limiting (e.g., `gitk path/to/file`).

Comment: @RobertVuković I know this is an old question... but see my answer below!

Answer (score 7):

`git log --all -- path/to/file` should work

Comment: There's no link in my answer @ineersa

Comment: This should be the top answer. I dislike using crappy gui tools

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit in your answer? E.g., why is option `--all` required? What is it supposed to do? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Check the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all

Comment: @EdsonMedina Instead of putting the link to documentation in the comment, it would be better to put it into the answer and copy the relevant parts of it here. "RTFM" (even without the F) sounds arrogant.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, if you want something as close to TortoiseSVN as possible, you could just use [TortoiseGit](http://TortoiseGit.GoogleCode.Com/).

Comment: Except that the TortoiseSvn shell extensions contain a command for showing the history of a single file, whereas TortoiseGit does not.

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) also provides a [command line tool](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html) to do see the history of a file. Using [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

```
C:\Program` Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\path\to\your\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [git-diff](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-diff.html) or [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).