# See changes to a specific file using git

Tags: git, git-svn

I know that I can use the `git diff` command to check the changes, but, as far as I understood, it is directory based. This means it gives all the changes of all files on the current directory.

*How can I check only the changes in one specific file?* Say, I have changed files `file_1.rb`, `file_2.rb`, ..., `file_N.rb`, but I am only interested in the changes in the file `file_2.rb`. How do I check these changes then (before I commit)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view file history in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786027/how-to-view-file-history-in-git)

Comment: My main question is how to check the difference for a specific file before I commit all the changes. Git log is for committed changes I guess.

Comment: In my experiencie is better to use a visual tool like [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com)

Answer (score 929, accepted):

Use a command like:

```
git diff file_2.rb
```

See the [`git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for full information on the kinds of things you can get differences for.

Normally, `git diff` by itself shows all the changes in the whole *repository* (not just the current directory).

Comment: If you want to see a file's changes that you've already "git add"'ed, it's "git diff --cached"

Comment: If  you want to check a file against an older commit:
$ git diff [commit hash]  file_2.rb

Comment: How to exit from  diff view ?

Comment: Or use SourceTree.

Comment: @GurpreetsinghDhanju Try pressing Q

Comment: Please update answer with @PaulBetts remark on files already `git add`-ed.

Answer (score 248):

Another method (mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493663/1505416)) will keep the history in the terminal and give you a very deep track record of the file itself:

`git log --follow -p -- file`

> This will show the entire history of the file (including history beyond renames and with diffs for each change).
>
> In other words, if the file named bar was once named foo, then git log -p bar (without the --follow option) will only show the file's history up to the point where it was renamed -- it won't show the file's history when it was known as foo. Using git log --follow -p bar will show the file's entire history, including any changes to the file when it was known as foo.

Comment: Works nicely with --stat to have an overview of the lines added / deleted.

Comment: Yes this answer should rank at least higher, tracks the history, not just the current diff, nor do you have to keep track of all the commit hashes. Pretty simple usage yet very powerfull in changes

Comment: I used --oneline; and --shortstat for a quick summary of changes. I have long PR descriptions and templates.

Answer (score 112):

You can use `gitk [filename]` to see the changes log

Comment: This would show the history of the commits on the file, which sometimes might be what you need.

Answer (score 41):

You can use below command to see who have changed what in a file.

`git blame <filename>`

Comment: This is the best answer as it tells you who made what change, and when as well as which commit the change was part of. To filter for a specific change, just do `git blame <filename> | grep <searchfor>` where `<searchfor>` is a short value. For example, to find out who changed `foo` to `bar` in `dist/index.php`, you would use `git blame dist/index.php | grep bar`

Answer (score 36):

to list only commits details for specific file changes,

```
git log --follow file_1.rb
```

to list difference among various commits for same file,

```
git log -p file_1.rb
```

to list only commit and its message,

```
git log --follow --oneline file_1.rb
```

Answer (score 25):

You can execute

```
git status -s
```

This will show modified files name and then by copying the interested file path you can see changes using `git diff`

```
git diff <filepath + filename>
```

Answer (score 19):

you can also try

```
git show <filename>
```

For commits, *git show* will show the log message and textual diff (between your file and the commited version of the file).

You can check [git show Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) for more info.

Answer (score 14):

git diff filename

will give you
added lines as +
removed lines as -

Comment: i think this only works if not committed. but maybe you can specify revisions ?

Answer (score 5):

you can use tig :

`sudo apt install tig`

you just type :  `tig` in your console

you could have something like this , you could browse the commits and the local changes for every code line

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Totally agree with @Greg Hewgill

And if you path includes spaces, you might use, try adding with apostrophe `'` or `

git diff 'MyProject/My Folder/My Sub Folder/file_2.rb'

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `git log` with `-p`

```
git log -p path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you prefer to use your own gui tool:

```
git difftool ./filepath
```

You can set your gui tool guided by this post:
[How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git diff` by passing a commit range, and a path preceded by `--`. For example to see the changes made to a file in the last commit of the current branch as compared to the tip of the current branch, you can use the `HEAD~1` shorthand:

```
git diff HEAD~1 -- <path to file>
```