# Is there a way to see only a single change of git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

Imagine for 3 files, for each I have made 2 changes. In total 6 changes.

Does `git diff` have any options to limit `git diff` to see one change at a time? And then move onto to the next change? i.e. I'd see 6 separate changes?

Comment: I doubt it. You can vie individual files as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048584/see-changes-to-a-specific-file-using-git)., but git doesn't store each individual change only how each file has been changed.

Comment: @joshmeranda Thanks. Is there a way to see file by file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here; what's the state of the repo and what do you mean by 2 changes in each file? If you're looking to review work in progress, maybe `git add -p`?

Comment: I think `git add -p` is a great alternative. Can you put that into an answer? I honestly didn't have a certain state in mind. I just wanted it to be interactive. I mean e.g. at line 12 there's a change and at like 52 there's another change in the same file.

Comment: @Honey `git diff <path>`, if you look at the help for [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) you can read a bit more if you don't go with the `git  add -p` route as @johrsharpe suggests although they will provide similar functionality (diff will not allow you to add as you review)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to JonSharpe's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094642/is-there-a-way-to-see-only-a-single-change-of-git-diff#comment122118182_69094642), the closest thing to what I asked to do is:

```
git add -p
```

With the only note that it works for **unstaged** changes. There is no such thing as `git diff -p`. And `git diff <path>` isn't interactive as you have to manually enter the path yourself.