# Why I got errors with git history commands?

Tags: git

Under Kubuntu 18 with project at bitbucket I need to review all changes during development made to some file.

I found this [How to view file history in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786027/how-to-view-file-history-in-git) branch ,
but trying to check all updates of resources/js/app.js file I got errors :

```
user@projectpath$ git log  resources/js/app.js
fatal: ambiguous argument 'resources/js/app.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

user@projectpath$ git diff  resources/js/app.js
fatal: ambiguous argument 'resources/js/app.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

user@projectpath$ git whatchanged  resources/js/app.js
fatal: ambiguous argument 'resources/js/app.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I do not see why error? Or other version of git ?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

Also I tried to run command :

```
gitk --follow  resources/js/app.js
```

But invalid argument errors...
Which way is valid ?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this file actually committed? What does `git status` say? Is there a `*.js` in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: I hope you understand that all of the commands you're trying have the same issue...they don't recognize `resources/js/app.js`.  This isn't a git version thing.  The behavior of git in this case will likely not have changed over time. It seems pretty clear that the file `resources/js/app.js` isn't under Git version control.  Does the file exist (try `ls resources/js/app.js`)?  As @FantasticMrFox says, do `git status`, or even better, `git status --ignored`.  The latter will show you even files that are normally ignored by git due to being matched by one of your `.gitignore` files.

Comment: ... if `git status --ignored` shows that file, or either the `js` or `resource` subdirectories, then that file isn't currently under git's control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git told you:

> ```
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> ```

That is:

```
git log -- resources/js/app.js
```

You will *need* the `--` here if the file is not currently checked out.  Otherwise, it's *sometimes* optional.  Get in the habit of using it, so that you use it automatically whenever it is not optional.